# Remove getters and setters from kotlin code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing

For this code

```
class Foo {
    var name: String? = null
}
```

kotlin compiler generates:

```
private String name;
public final String getName() { ... }
public final void setName(String name) { ... }
```

Even if property `name` doesn't have custom getter or setter.
It's possible to remove redundant get and set methods using `@JvmField` annotation. So this code

```
class Foo {
    @JvmField
    var name: String? = null
}
```

generates only one field without additional methods.

```
public String name;
```

But is there any way to make kotlin compiler **not** generate getters and setters for all properties in entire project? No matter if it has annotation or not. Maybe some experimental compiler flags?

I want it because I have android instrumentation tests written on kotlin. Test apk exceeds 65k method count limit. About 2k of methods is generated getters/setters.  I cannot use proguard or multidex due to some bugs in android build system. So removing kotlin synthetic methods will help me a lot.

Comment: this page:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#testing    and couple of comments in google issue tracker say that "Using multidex to create a test APK is not currently supported."

Comment: Remove synthetic getters and setters is just a one step to optimize method count in my apk. But if there is compiler options or something like that it would be great. I can easily remove 2k methods.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear. Not my app apk exceeds limit. It easily can be solved with multidex. Apk that contains all my test code and test libs exceeds limit. And this apk cannot be proguarded nor multidexed due to android build system bugs.

Comment: Removed comment, as I see what you're trying to achieve! Can you not use `minifyEnabled true` with `useProguard false` in your build configuration?

Comment: There is no such compiler option. d8 (the replacement for dex tool) might be able to remove accessors, but I'm not sure if the functionality is currently implemented.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I'll try d8

Answer (score 3):

You can simply declare your properties as `private`, they won’t have getters and setters generated then.

```
class Foo {
  private val foo: String = "foo"
}
```

This will generate the following class:

```
→ javap -classpath build/classes/kotlin/test -p test.Foo
Compiled from "Foo.kt"
public final class test.Foo {
  private final java.lang.String foo;
  public test.Foo();
}
```

Comment: It is not a solution